# Select query result inside WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

Hello I am trying to make a WHERE clause where the condition is the id of the previous selection, example:

```
     SELECT 
        ,P1.caseid
        ,(SELECT SUM(P1.amount) FROM table_s P1 WHERE P1.status = 4 AND P1.caseid = 20) 
        as variable
        FROM table_s P1 GROUP BY P1.caseid";
```

let's say each iteration the `P1.caseid` have value of

```
20,
45,
20,
```

How I can insert this value to be the condition of the `WHERE` clause here: WHERE `P1.status = 4 AND P1.caseid = 20`

Instead of `P1.caseid` to be = to 20 it have to be equal to the actual `caseid` inside the database for each row.

So for each row it will be:

```
WHERE P1.caseid = 20 
WHERE P1.caseid = 45 
WHERE P1.caseid = 35
```

In this case the number is eqaul to the caseid inside the DB.

**TABLE NAME: table_s**

```
id | caseid | amount | status 
-- | ------------------------
 1 | 20     | 10     | 4
 2 | 45     | 10     | 4
 3 | 20     | 10     | 4
```

DB is as follows, the result should be:

```
1 ROW = caseid: 20 amount: 20 status 4
2 ROW = caseid: 45 amount: 10 status 4
```

Or

```
$variable = 20
$variable = 10
```

Comment: You're not making a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Yiur question is not clear ... show a proper sample of data and the result  you expected ..

Comment: proper sample of data and expected result are added.

Comment: So you want `where case_id in (20, 45)`

Comment: you say 'FROM status P1' - that means status is the name of the table and you are going to use P1 to call its columns, then say 'WHERE P1.status' - is there a column named 'status' in a table named 'status'? As @scaisEdge said, you need to show the table definition, some data, and what you'd like to pull out with the query.

Comment: I have changed the table name to make it more clear and have put additional code. case_id (20, 45) is unknown value it can be anything depending on what is stored inside the table_s

Comment: SQL doesn't iterate over a set of data row-by-agonising-row in a pre-defined order.  So the idea of one output rows being dependant on the previous output row is going to send you down a lot of blind alleys.  For that you should be using SAS or something.  In SQL, however, there most likely is an approach, and it sounds like you just need a straight aggregation.  What is wrong with `SELECT caseid, SUM(amount), MAX(status) FROM table_s GROUP BY caseid ORDER BY caseid`?

Comment: ...once you've understood the concept of a PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: table has it's primary key which is id.

Comment: the idea is to select the sum of the amount for each caseid and display it. as caseid - sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've worked out what you're asking...

The important note here is to use *different* aliases for your table in the outer and inner queries.  Otherwise you have a serious scope problem. *(If two instances of the same entity have the same name, how can MySQL ever know which one you're referring to?  It will choose the one in the nearest scope.  So, instead, call one of them, for example, `lookup`.)*

```
SELECT 
    P1.*,
    (
     SELECT SUM(lookup.amount)
       FROM table_s   lookup
      WHERE lookup.status = 4
        AND lookup.caseid = P1.caseid
    )
        correlated_sub_query_total_by_caseid
FROM
    table_s P1
```

But that itself can be re-written without the correlated sub-query...

```
SELECT 
    P1.*,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN amount END)   AS status_3_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 4 THEN amount END)   AS status_4_total
FROM
    table_s P1
INNER JOIN
    table_s lookup
        ON lookup.caseid = P1.caseid
GROUP BY
    P1.primary_key
```

That said, you added another comment that seems to contract your question...

`the idea is to select the sum of the amount for each caseid and display it. as caseid - sum`

For that you just need an aggregation...

```
SELECT
    caseid,
    SUM(amount)
FROM
    table_s
GROUP BY
    caseid
```

And if you only want to aggregate where the status is 3 or 4...

```
SELECT
    caseid,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END)   status_3_total
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END)   status_4_total
FROM
    table_s
GROUP BY
    caseid
```

Comment: You've go it! this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: first solution worked, because I have another query which is selecting same case id but with P1.status = 3 for example as variable2

Comment: @JohnSiniger - Without knowing what you're doing this for, or seeing the full query, it's hard to comment.  But note that this correlated sub-query is not going to be very efficient.

Comment: @JohnSiniger - See my latest edit, use what is currently the second query.  Having multiple correlated sub-queries is going to be *extremely* inefficient.  *(But I'm still lost as to why the simple aggregations in the end of my answer don't work for you.)*

Comment: basically it is this: `SELECT 
    P1.*,
    (
     SELECT SUM(lookup.amount)
       FROM table_s   lookup
      WHERE lookup.status = 4
        AND lookup.caseid = P1.caseid
    )
        correlated_sub_query_total_by_caseid_status_eql_3
    ,
    (
     SELECT SUM(lookup.amount)
       FROM table_s   lookup
      WHERE lookup.status = 3
        AND lookup.caseid = P1.caseid
    )
        correlated_sub_query_total_by_caseid_status_eql_3
FROM
    table_s P1
GROUP BY
    P1.caseid`

Comment: @JohnSiniger - Use my last query.

Comment: Very elegant solution the last one! Thank you very much!

Comment: Shows that it's better to ask how to solve a functional requirement, rather than how to implement a technical solution.